# Numpy .in1d method not evaluating array vs array view correctly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to search and see if a numpy array is within another for debugging something.

```
#Pattern
arr1 = np.array([1.62434536, -0.61175641, -0.52817175])
#type : np.ndarray
#dtype : 'float64'
#shape : (3,)
```

Then I have a **list** of **tuples**, where the first element in each tuple is a n by m **ndarray**
Lets say this object is called 'my_nest'

```
arr2 = my_nest[0][0][0][0:3]
arr2
#array([ 1.62434536, -0.61175641, -0.52817175])
#type : np.ndarray
#dtype : 'float64'
#shape : (3,)
```

But then using the in1d method returns an unintuitive result

```
np.in1d(arr1,arr2)
#array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

I know slicing an ndarray creates a view of the object as it is in memory, but I even tried wrapping np.copy around it to create a new object in memory and then compare and I still get False.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: What is the result of `arr1 == arr2`?

Comment: Or `arr1-arr2`.  Equality tests on floats can be unreliable.

Comment: @hpaulj. The ordering appears to be the same, and `in1d` uses equality testing as far as I know. In general of course, subtraction is more informative.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments this is an effect of floating point precision. You can reimplement `in1d` according to its [source for small arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/fb215c76967739268de71aa4bda55dd1b062bc2e/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L581-L584) using [`isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) instead of `==`.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1.62434536, -0.61175641, -0.52817175])
arr2 = np.array([1.62434536, -0.61175641, -0.52817175+1e-12])
print(arr1)
print(arr2)

print('isin:   ', np.in1d(arr1,arr2))

mask = np.zeros(len(arr1), dtype=bool)
for a in arr2:
    mask |= np.isclose(arr1, a)
print('isclose:', mask)
```

Output:

```
[ 1.62434536 -0.61175641 -0.52817175]
[ 1.62434536 -0.61175641 -0.52817175]
isin:    [ True  True False]
isclose: [ True  True  True]
```